# getting bind exception while trying to get list of all topics in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using the following command to get the list of all topics in kafka

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9999; nested exception is:
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
```

my kafka version is `0.10.1.0`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm coming to this so late, but I had this issue today and this post helped me figure out a working solution, so I thought I'd post my workaround.  I have tested this with both Kafka v2.0 and 1.0 under Cloudera (née Hortworks) HDP v3.1 and 2.6.5, respectively.

As suggested in the earlier answers, kafka-run-class.sh needs to be updated.  You indicate that you're running ./bin/kafka-topics.sh; the run class script should be along side the topics script in that same directory.  On my Hadoop brokers, the path is /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/

Find this section of the script:

```
# JMX port to use
if [ $ISKAFKASERVER = "true" ]; then
    JMX_REMOTE_PORT=$JMX_PORT
else
    JMX_REMOTE_PORT=$CLIENT_JMX_PORT
fi
```

And change it to:

```
# JMX port to use
if [ $ISKAFKASERVER = "true" ]; then
    JMX_REMOTE_PORT=$JMX_PORT
else
    JMX_REMOTE_PORT=$CLIENT_JMX_PORT
    unset KAFKA_OPTS
fi
```

This assumes, of course, that the JMX port is set upstream via $KAFKA_OPTS and that you don't need any special settings.

I haven't tested it, but in theory unsetting JMX_PORT would work as well, and you could always override the KAFKA_OPTS value with something like KAFKA_OPTS="my special options".

Answer (score 0):

The port 9999 sounds to me to be the JMX port. Have you enabled the JMX port on the broker side (setting JMX_PORT and KAFKA_JMX_OPTS env vars) ? If yes, Have you set these env vars system wise ? 
The kafka-topics.sh command, as all the other tools, uses kafka-run-class.sh internally which launch the Java Class (TopicCommand in your case). If the above env vars are set in the console where you are launching the tool, it tries to enable JMX there as well conflicting with JMX port enabled in the broker. Can you confirm if the above variables are set ?

Comment: `# JMX port to use

if [  $JMX_PORT ]; then
  KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="$KAFKA_JMX_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT "
fi`
these lines I found in `kafka-run-class.sh`

Comment: Yes this is the code I already know, you have to tell me if in your environment such variables are set.

Comment: I haven't configured kafka.. I dont know where to see it... can you please tell me how to know whether they are set or not.. I mean in which file I have to see or any command is there to know this info

Comment: What do you mean "I haven't configured Kafka" ... are you running the Kafka broker ? Are you on Linux or Windows ? Checking env vars is not a Kafka related problem.

Comment: I am running kafka on linux,

Comment: I should not help on this because "Google" is a simple tool for searching a topic like this btw ... just the "env" command gives you all the env variables.

Comment: I checked, there is no JMX_PORT and KAFKA_JMX_OPTS in the env vars